# Website not scrolling on Windows Surface Tablet

Tags: windows, scroll, surface

Has anyone come across any issues for websites not scrolling on Windows Surface Tablet's?

Just launched a site & the client uses Surface Tablet's and say the site will not scroll at all.

Any hint's, tip's or solution?

Comment: Could you provide a link to your website?

Comment: here you go: http://www.orchardsoflondon.com